# “Disk space full” - Linux Mint as Dual Boot on UEFI Windows

Tags: windows, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to install Linux Mint 17.1 in UEFI mode on an Asus PC with Windows 8.1 preinstalled.

The 250GB-SSD with Windows preinstalled is /dev/sdb/. I partitioned 125GB for use with Ubuntu (Linux Mint 17.1). I set up my Linux partitions as follows:

1. 40GB for root / (tried with 20GB before)
2. 81GB for /home/
3. 4GB as swap.

At some point I get the warning "Disk space full" for the root directory ("/"). Increasing the partition size from 20 to 40GB did not prevent the warning.

When I look at the partition using "Disk" it shows it as full to within about 2GB. Something seems to be loading stuff onto there.

What is going on and how can I install Linux Mint as dual-boot with Windows in UEFI mode?

Answer (score 0):

Log files were filling up the disk space in /var/log. I just deleted the /log folder and created a new one with 'mkdir log'.

Comment: I usually put /var on a separate partition to avoid that. You might also want to figure out exactly what it is that is creating all those logs, otherwise the problem will recur.

Comment: I also used `logrotate` on the log files.

Answer (score 0):

You could have expanded the partition without expanding the filesystem. But if you used gparted for partition expansion, the filesystem should have been adjusted too. You can also analyse the filesystem contents, where the most space is used. You can use `du -hs /*`, but I recommend gdmap. Possibly you can reduce disk usage be uninstalling old kernels, deleting old log files and by deleting the cache from apt.

Comment: Please note that clarifying questions ("How much used space...?") should be asked as Comments on the question. Please reserve Answers for solutions (such as "use `du -hs /*`..."). Thank you!

Comment: I would do that, but don't have have the right to comment yet (I can comment on my on answers). If you comment to the question for me, I will delete the question from my answer. I also tried to include solutions to my answer, not just the clarifying question.

Comment: I would, but as I've read further, I noticed that the OP answered their own question the following day with "log files in /var/log", so it's probably not worth asking this particular follow-up question. I noticed you were relatively new to U&L Stack Exchange so I wanted to guide your future behavior; "Answers" that are *only* comments/questions themselves are subject to deletion, so it'd be good if you could go ahead and remove the question from your answer. Thank you, and welcome to U&L!

Comment: I didn't realize that the other answer was from OP, else I wouldn't have bothered answering at all. Thanks for your guidance, I try to make better answers in the furure (or comments, when I get the privilege)